# Regex match any setence containing ^ except those that start with \

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to add a delimiter -- `$` -- to each sentence that contains an exponential -- `^` -- operator in my text, but I don't want to add this same delimiter when the base of my exponential contains a backslash in it. I tried to use the `((?!\\\w+)\w+)\^(\w+)` regex to no success.

| input | what I want | what I got |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo^2 | $foo^2$ | $foo^2$ |
| \foo^2 | \foo^2 | $foo^2$ |

My code:

```py
from re import sub

sentence = """foo^2 
 \bar, \bar^3 
bar 
\foo 
 \bar
 foo^5 
"""

sub(r'((?!\\\w+)\w+)\^(\w+)', '$\\1^\\2$', sentence)
```

Gives the following output:

```py
'$foo^2$ \n \x08ar, \x08$ar^3$ \nbar \n\x0coo \n \x08ar\n $foo^5$ \n'
```

Comment: Is the backslash always at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Yes, @WaisKamal

Comment: You need to use a negative look-behind assertion, and also match word-boundaries: e.g. `r'(?<!\\)\b(\w+)\^(\w+)\b'`. (And note that your example string needs to be a *raw-string*, otherwise it will contain embedded control characters, like `\b` and `\f`).

Comment: That's it, @ekhumoro.

Comment: @LucasAlmeidaCarotta One other point: can the input include escaped backslashes? If so, that might need special handling. (For example, something like `\\foo^2`).

Comment: You forgot to use `r` prefix before your string literal. `"\b"` is a BACKSPACE char, `\x08`, and `r"\b"` is a two char string containing ``\`` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
import re
texts = [r'foo^2', r'\foo^2']
for text in texts:
    print(re.sub(r'(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*\b\w+)\^(\w+)', r'$\1^\2$', text))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Df35cX).

| Output: |
| --- |
| `$foo^2$` |
| `\foo^2` |

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Suzj47/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\\)` - a location not immediately preceded with aa `\` char
- `((?:\\\\)*\b\w+)` - Group 1: zero or more `\\` string occurrences, a word boundary and one or more word chars
- `\^` - a `^` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars.

Answer (score 0):

@Lucas Almeida Carotta, is that what you want?

```
sentence = r"""foo^2 
 \bar, \bar^3 
bar 
\foo 
 \bar
 foo^5 
"""

new_words = []

new_words = []

for word in sentence.split():
    if (re.search('^\\\\', word)):
        new_words.append(word)
        #print(word.replace('\\',''))
    else:
        #print('$'+word+'$')
        new_words.append('$'+word+'$')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
print(new_words)

['$foo^2$', '\\bar,', '\\bar^3', '$bar$', '\\foo', '\\bar', '$foo^5$']
```

Comment: I fixed the question. I want the backslash to be presented.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: @VictorSaraivaRocha Your solution adds "\" where there isn't one. Also, it strips out all the whitespace, so the original text cannot be reconstructed.